# What words are used to mean in relation to or origin of a planet?

Tags: solar-system

Pretty simple question I think, but I am having trouble confirming a legitimate answer.

**If things related to Mars are Martian, things related to Jupiter are Jovian, and things related to the Moon are Lunar, what do we call things related to the other major stellar bodies?**

So far I have used Venusian for Venus, although I am unsure if this is incorrect, and there are a few names for things from Earth (Earthborn, Terran, etc...). I am just hesitant to follow simpler English naming conventions if there is already a more official term.

This is what I am thinking at the moment, but feel like it doesn't sound entirely right:

- ***Sun - Solar***
- Mercury - Mercurian
- Venus - Venusian
- ***Moon (Luna) - Lunar***
- ***Mars - Martian***
- ***Jupitar - Jovian***
- Ganymede - Ganymean
- Europa - Europan
- Saturn - Saturnal
- Titan - Titan (unsure if there is need for suffix)
- Uranus - Uranian (Uranan?)
- Neptune - Neptunal
- Pluto - Plutonal (Plutan? Plutonian?)
- Eris - Erissian

Please let me know if any of these are incorrect, or if there isn't an official naming convention.

Comment: different but related question: [How do apsides of celestial bodies get their names?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/6639/12102)

Comment: Nice question ! Checked out on Wiktionary and almost all adjectives are ending with "-ian", like Neptunian, Plutonian, Uranian, Titanian, Saturnian, Ganymedian and indeed Venusian and Mercurian. The exception of course is Europa that will be Europe**a**n ! Found nothing about Eris .

Comment: Wikipedia has a list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_of_astronomical_bodies

Comment: @DavidHammen That answers it perfectly. Apparently there are several names that can be used for each. Thank you very much. If you put it as an official answer I will choose that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Wikipedia page has the information you're looking for with references:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_of_astronomical_bodies

So for example:

```
Mercurian, Hermean
Venerian, Venusian
Terran
    lunar, Selenian
Martian
Jovian
    Ganymedean
    Europan
Saturnian
    Titanian
Uranian
Neptunian
Plutonian
Eridian
    Dysnomian
```